# Composer (php) unknown error after update

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I changed my hosting and dev container. In the process, Composer got updated to version 2.4.2 (latest).

Now, if I run `composer update` or `composer install` (after removing the lock file), I always get this error:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

<comment>In LoadConfiguration.php line 66:</comment>
<error>    </error>
<error>    </error>
<error>    </error>
```

But running `php artisan package:discover --ansi` works just fine!
My `.env` file is also good (LF line endings, all variables with strange characters are in double quotes..)

I also tried to rename the vendor folder and reinstall everything, but I still get this error. What can I do?
Thank you!

---

```
$ composer diagnose
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: WARNING
Your git version (2.17.1) is too old and possibly will cause issues. Please upgrade to git 2.24 or above
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: *************
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: ************
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 2.4.2
PHP version: 8.1.10
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php8.1
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
cURL version: 7.58.0 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1
zip: extension present, unzip present, 7-Zip not available
```

---

opened issue with Composer, but it's probably an issue with my configuration https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/11069

---

tried to downgrade php to v8.0.2, same problem

Comment: Seems there is a namespace mismatch between Class App\Models\Faq and ./app/Models/paki/Faq.php

Comment: Hi, I'm not using the models in that folder. Anyways, I corrected the namespace path, but Composer still fails in the same way. I'll remove this part from the question

Comment: Try removing `vendor/` folder completely and then do `composer install`

Comment: hi, thank you for the suggestion. I already tried, got the same result

Comment: Why did you remove the lock file?

Comment: for testing. I renamed it actually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem "solved" by rolling back composer to version 2.0.9

hopefully the guys at Composer will fix the bug

Comment: Did you report that bug anywhere? Composer 2.0.9 is pretty old

Comment: I did report the bug, there's link to that in the body of my question. They don't believe it's their problem. 
I used v2.0.9 because that's what I had running in the WSL host, and it worked. So I used it in the container too.